# Combining CMakeLists.txt, boost-python with python setuptools

Tags: python, c++, boost, itk

I have a project where I interface ITK code with boost-python to compile a .so file which I can include in my python projects. As I have discovered, compiling an ITK module is the most convenient when you use CMake.

If I wish to distribute this as a python package, what would be the most robust way to call cmake to generate my .so and install this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be creating a remote module and using ITK infrastructure to build a python package. Docs: https://itkpythonpackage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Build_ITK_Module_Python_packages.html